# How to change default MS-Word font programatically

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am trying to set Word default font, using C# VSTO Add-In. I know I can do it manually like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-in-word-2f50603b-9886-47e4-a483-48ac5ab80163).

I also can do it like this:

```
doc.Font.Name = "<some font name here>";
```

But how can I set the **default** font **programatically** ?